# d3.js Line Chart -- Need to load an arbitrary number of data series

Tags: javascript, plot, d3.js

I'm working with a D3.js line chart and I get the data with this code :

```
// Get the data
d3.tsv("data2.tsv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close; // 1st line of data
        d.open = +d.open; // 2sd line of data
    });

    ...

}
```

Here is my data file in tsv :

```
date    close   open
1-May-12    58.13   34.12
30-Apr-12   53.98   45.56
27-Apr-12   67.00   67.89
26-Apr-12   89.70   78.54
25-Apr-12   99.00   89.23
24-Apr-12   130.28  99.23
23-Apr-12   166.70  101.34
```

I want to make a widget to generate this graph with an arbitrary number of lines on my Graph (as opposed to the hardcoded two lines as shown).

How can I process an arbitrary number of data series in the same foreach clause (see code) ?

Comment: mmm, the foreach loops over all data rows. In your comments you probably mean "1st column of data"?

Comment: Yes sorry, it's to get the columns of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just process the data and assuming that date will always be present (otherwise, what will be used for the x-axis?):

```
d3.tsv("data2.tsv", function(error, data) {
    //create array of all the none date keys
    var keyArray = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key){ return key != 'date'; });

    //iterate over every row from the tsv
    data.forEach(function(row) {
        //cast date as a datetime
        row.date = parseDate(row.date);

        //cast everything else as a number
        keyArray.forEach(function(key){ row[key] = +row[key]; });
    });

    ...

});
```

To graph and color several lines w/o hard coding column names: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3884955

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it seems perfect ! :)
But I still have a question : How can I get the data after the foreach ? because the table is empty :/

Comment: Hun sorry, row is not empty, it is undefined.

Comment: And on the x-Axis it will be just some numbers. So, your code is perfect for that.

Comment: Did you update this line: 

"data.forEach(function(row) {"
 
     Try copying and pasting what I posted into your code. If that doesn't work, post a link to jsfiddle with what you have.

Comment: It doesn't work with a copy paste, I will post a jsfiddle tomorrow morning.
Thanks

Comment: Hi! Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Q3ATd/2/
As you can see on the console, row is undefined :/

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3ATd/5/   row is only defined inside of function(row){ ... }   see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet for more about varible scope in javascript